# destroy server side user session from webview android

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to clear session and cookies from webview and server for that

```
public static void clearCookies(Context context)
{

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        Log.d("C.TAG", "Using clearCookies code for API >=" + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1));
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
        CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
    } else
    {
        Log.d("C.TAG", "Using clearCookies code for API <" + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1));
        CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr=CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
        cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
        CookieManager cookieManager=CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
        cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
        cookieSyncMngr.sync();
    }
}
```

as above code clear session & cookies from device webview but here I need to destroy current user session from server side like basically logout button do.

Actually I want to restrict multiple server side user session creating after above code run.

Comment: For that you must create a `Http Request` to the server.

Comment: yes @VaibhavGoyal  same I thought so before that I have to sure this one correct solution or any other callback method/other way to encounter issue... thanks for your suggestion :)